# Spring Interceptor has different traceId for afterCompletion method with Spring sleuth 3.x.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am currently working on a Spring boot project. Recently I upgraded the version of my Spring boot from 2.3.3 to 2.6.6. In Spring boot 2.3.3 I was using Spring cloud sleuth 2.x.x which now has been upgraded to 3.x.x due to the Spring cloud dependency management BOM. The POM is as follows

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2021.0.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I have an interceptor as follows

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class RequestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

@Autowired
private Tracer tracer;

@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
        throws Exception {
    log.info("Execution completed with traceId: {}", tracer.currentSpan().context().traceIdString());
}
```

Earlier this code was giving me the same traceId for all the logs for that particular request. But with Spring sleuth 3.x.x I'm getting a different traceId in afterCompletion() of the Spring Interceptor. Can someone please help

**Note:** I know this is a deliberate example but I have a similar code in my project

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug in Sleuth it seems or some behaviour has changed in Reactor / WebClient - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/2075

Comment: It is not related to WebClient. To test this, I created an endpoint in my Spring application that doesn't call any further APIs. I'm still facing this issue @Marcin Grzejszczak

Comment: I see... Are you using Tomcat? Which server are you using?

Comment: Yes. I'm using Tomcat. FYI, we are using both spring-web & spring-webflux

Comment: That's surprising cause we're instrumenting Tomcat's Valve so you should have instrumentation at a very early and late stages. Hmm unless the `HandlerInterceptor#afterCompletion` is being called after Tomcat's Valve instrumentation is done. You'd need to put a breakpoint at `TraceValve` code to see if span.end() is not getting called before the `afterCompletion` code gets executed

Comment: Ok. I will check on it and get back. Btw, will span.end() also change the traceId? Ideally TraceId shouldn't change right. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I found some insights based on your suggestion to debug `TraceValve`. This issue is specifically for reactive types when returned from the Controller. When the controller returns a Mono/Flux the control is sent back to `invoke` method in `TraceValve` and there is a `finally` block in that method which is ending the span by calling `handleSend` method of `HttpServerHandler` class. I checked the older version of sleuth (i.e., 2.2.8.RELEASE) where there is a class similar to `TraceValve` i.e., `TracingFilter` that has a similar finally block but has a if-else check to check for ASYNC types.

Comment: I believe we should be dealing reactive & non-reactive code in a similar way (i.e., by having an if-else check). In sleuth 3.x.x `TraceValve` class's `invoke` method the finally block is changing the span (i.e., ending the old span and creating a new one) for ASYNC types. 1 reason this could be happening is since for reactive types the control is immediately sent back without waiting synchronously. I tried to change the reactive return type in controller to a non-reactive type and the span.end() was being done after we get a response (i.e., after synchronous processing)